# How to involve more cpu cores?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

I'm working on Mathematica 11 (Lenovo Laptop, Core i7 cpu, 16GB Ram, SSD storage, windows 10 pro), part of my work is definite double integral, the evaluation time of this integral takes between 50 to 200 minutes. Is there a command in Mathematica that enables the use of more cpu cores to evaluate faster?
Best regards 
Sarmad.

Comment: the nature of the computation itself must be such that parts of it can evaluate in parallel to take advantage of more than one core at same time. If the algorithm is sequential  in nature, requiring step A to be completed before step B, then having 100 cores or one core will take the same time, since step B must wait until step A is completed. I assume you are you doing symbolic integration and not numerical. Under possible issues for parallelize, it says `Expressions that cannot be parallelized are evaluated normally:`  with symbolic Integrate example saying it be  can't be parallelized.

Comment: Hi Sarmad, welcome to Mma.SE. Thanks for taking the [tour]! Be sure to learn about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always show due diligence, for instance by sharing  what you learned when you [searched the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ParallelComputing.html), and why the information there wasn't enough. Include **minimal working example** of code you are working on. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely will inspire great answers.

Comment: I suggest that you add your code in  Mathematica format to your question.